# Post json of unknown class with Feign client

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, feign

My service has to redirect a json data to another service. In all examples I saw on feign client, sender knows the data type of the sent object, and so it looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping("some/path", consumes = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE])
interface UploadClient {

    @PostMapping("upload")
    fun upload(book: Book): Long
}
```

My problem is I have no Book class, I just have to forward json. I've tried to do it with String, like this:

Client interface:

```
@RequestMapping("some/path")
interface UploadClient {

    @PostMapping("/upload", consumes = arrayOf(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
    fun import(@RequestBody strangeData: String): Long

}
```

Feign Factory:

```
class DefaultFeignClientFactory() : FeignClientFactory {

override fun <T> getClient(target: Class<T>, url: String): T {
    return registry.getOrPut(target) {
        Feign.builder()
            .target(target, url)
    } as T
}

}
```

Client is instantiated using OSGi:

```
  <bean id="uploadClient" factory-ref="feignClientFactory" factory-method="getClient">
    <argument value="com.blah.blahblah.UploadClient"/>
  </bean>
```

And the same interface on the receiver side is:

```
 @RequestMapping("some/path")
 interface Loader {

     @PostMapping("/upload")
     fun import(@RequestBody myBooks: Collection<Book>): Long

 }
```

If I throw json in the receiver directly (curl/postman/etc), it deserializes it and works fine.
Passing the string to feign client works, but unfortunately, receiver can't deserialize it that way.
So I tried to change it to byte[] (ByteArray in Kotlin):

```
    @PostMapping("/upload", consumes = arrayOf(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
    fun import(@RequestBody strangeData: ByteArray): Long
```

and it falls with `org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException message: Unsupported Media Type`
Same luck with `MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE` and `MediaType.ALL_VALUE` (actually ALL_VALUE fell with some other error) - data is not sent to the receiver service in any form.

What Java data type and what MediaType do I have to choose in those circumstances?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to state that your method is accepting generic JSON is by using Jackson's [JsonNode](https://static.javadoc.io/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.6/index.html?com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html) as your parameter type.

```
@RequestMapping(value = ["some/path"], consumes = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE])
interface UploadClient {

    @PostMapping("upload")
    fun upload(@RequestBody book: JsonNode): Long
}
```

This way, you are able to post JSON Objects, JSON Arrays, Strings, Numbers or Booleans with arbitrary nesting. Here's an example:

```
val book: ObjectNode = JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode()
        .put("authors", JsonNodeFactory.instance.arrayNode()
                .add("John Doe")
                .add("Jane Doe"))
        .put("title", "First Book about the Does")
        .put("year", 2018)

val id = uploadClient.upload(book)
```

This is equivalent to the following request

```
POST /some/path HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "authors": ["John Doe", "Jane Doe"],
  "title": "First Book about the Does",
  "year": 2018
}
```

Using JsonNode will also work on the server side.